# Ansible loses connection after API sends reboot to client

Tags: ansible

I created a role to set up our new servers but am running into one issue. The play triggers a Python script. This script submits information about the server to our API. The script eventually triggers a job from the API, and the server is rebooted by this job. The play does not end until the Python script completes. However, Ansible loses connection during the reboot, because the play itself didn't initiate the reboot, and the playbook fails. I have already tried the following.

```
- name: Run setup.py
  command: "{{ run_setup_py }} --username {{ username }} --password {{ password }} --ip {{ ansible_host }} --hostname {{ host_name }}"
  async: 1800
  poll: 60
```

This fails after `async` times out. It appears Ansible doesn't recognize that the script completed and fails. I attempted a few other `async` plays such as

```
- name: Run setup.py
  command: "{{ run_setup_py }} --username {{ username }} --password {{ password }} --ip {{ ansible_host }} --hostname {{ host_name }}"
  async: 600
  poll: 0
  register: run_setup
- name: check on async task
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ run_setup.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 1000
  delay: 450
```

No luck with either of the following. For some reason `wait_for_connection` at the play level was skipping the Python script entirely and causing later plays to fail.

```
- name: Wait until remote system is reachable
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 180
    sleep: 15
  delegate_to: localhost
```

```
- name: Wait until remote system is reachable
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 180
    sleep: 15
```

I attempted adding `ignore_unreachable: yes` at the playbook level. Ansible attempted to reconnect immediately but failed due to the server still in POST.

The script runs and works perfectly when run on the remote host so it isn't an issue with the script. The remaining steps of our setup **cannot** run until after the script is run.
At this point, any answer as to how to maintain Ansible's connection would be greatly appreciated. It *would* be ideal to not waste time if at all possible, e.g. constant connection checking.

My apologies if any information is missing or confusing, I've only been using Ansible for about a month now. Currently using ansible-core 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `wait_for` instead of `wait_for_connection`.  It is run locally:

```
- name: Run setup.py
  command: "{{ run_setup_py }} --username {{ username }} --password {{ password }}

- name: Wait for the reboot and reconnect
  wait_for:
    port: 22
    host: '{{ (ansible_ssh_host|default(ansible_host))|default(inventory_hostname) }}'
    search_regex: OpenSSH
    delay: 10
    timeout: 60
  connection: local

- name: Check the Uptime of the servers
  shell: "uptime"
  register: Uptime

- name: Show uptime
  debug:
    var: Uptime
```